# Is it possible to ignore all signals?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I have a server application which I want to protect from being stopped by any signal which I can ignore. Is there a way to ignore all possible signals at once, without setting them one by one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes:

```
#include <signal.h>

sigset_t mask;
sigfillset(&mask);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
```

This does not exactly *ignore* the signals, but blocks them; which in practice is the same effect.

I guess there's no need to mention that `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be blocked nor ignored in any way.

For more detailed semantics, like mask inheritance rules and the like, [check the man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sigprocmask.html)

Comment: Please, never forget to check the return values.  I skipped that part for brevity.

Comment: ... nor SIGABRT or SIGSEGV, I suppose.

Comment: @KerrekSB: You can actually catch SIGSEGV and SIGBUS, so I guess you can ignore them too.  At your own risk, of course.  The [signal(7)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) man page only mentions `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` though.

Comment: You can catch them, but you can't block them. That's different from SIGKILL I suppose.

Comment: Came here looking to see if indeed *all* signals can be caught/blocked, so definitely good to mention that `SIGSTOP` and `SIGKILL` can’t! :)

Comment: init(`pid`=1) and kernel threads are the exceptions which can block or ignore `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP`.

Answer (score 16):

*Blocking* signals is **NOT** the same as *ignoring* them.

When you block signals as suggested by C2H5OH, it gets added to a pending signal queue and will be delivered to the process as soon as you unblock it.

Unblocking can be done using

```
#include <signal.h>

sigset_t mask;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
```

To answer your question on how to ignore signals, it has to be handled by a Signal Handler which is a user-defined function which executes whenever a signal is delivered to the process

```
static void foo (int bar)
{
     /*some code here. In your case, nothing*/
}
```

then register this function by using

```
signal(SIGINT,foo);   //or whatever signal you want to ignore
```

If you want to ignore all signals

```
int i;
for(i = 1; i <=31 ; i++)
{
   signal(i,foo);
}
```

This code will take all the signals delivered to the process and ignore them instead of blocking them.

**NOTE**:

According to man pages , it is not the recommended way, instead sigaction is suggested. Do check out `man sigaction`

Answer (score 5):

Solutions based on `sigprocmask()` and `pthread_sigmask()` have not worked for me.
Here's what I found to work:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main() {
    struct sigaction act;
    act.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    for(int i = 1 ; i < 65 ; i++) {
        printf("i = %d\n", i);
        // 9 and 19 cannot be caught or ignored                                                                                                       
        // 32 and 33 do not exist                                                                                                                     
        if((i != SIGKILL) && (i != SIGSTOP) && (i != 32) && (i != 33)) {
            assert(sigaction(i, &act, NULL) == 0);
        }
    }
    sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```