# Create a non-stoppable program

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Can we create a program that can't be stopped by operating system? For ex. overriding all the signals like CTRL+C, CTRL+Z etc. so whenever operating system sends kill signal to the program it will simply ignore it.

Comment: Probably you are looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046916/is-it-possible-to-ignore-all-signals , try the accepted answer

Comment: Somehow Microsoft finds a way to right such programs.

Comment: SIGSTOP and SIGKILL cannot be ignored or treated.  You have to cope with that, or you'll have to rewrite some code in the kernel (and break it, making it non posix conformant)

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore most signals via the `signal` system call as follows:

```
signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
```

Here, we set the signal handler for `SIGINT` (which gets raised when you press CTRL+C) to be `SIG_IGN`, which is a special flag stating that that signal is to be ignored.

However, from the man page for `signal(2)`:

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught or ignored.

So while you can ignore a `SIGINT` (i.e. CTRL+C), you can't ignore `SIGSTOP` (CTRL+Z) or `SIGKILL`.